# Unit Of Work inside Transaction scope and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope, unit-of-work

I get an exception when I try to save an entity inside a `TransactionScope`, the exception I get is:

```
The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction
```

However on another machine I get a different exception on the same code block:

```
The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction
```

**The transaction implementation in my method is:**

```
    TransactionHelper.Transaction(() =>
    {
        if (sys.WfId.HasValue)
        {
            var sysData = GeneralMapping.GetSysData(model, ThisUser);
            DoAction(sys, model, sysData);

            if (!_sysClosed)
            {
                _Repository.InsertOrUpdate(sys);
                _Uow.Save();
            }
        }

    });
```

**TransactionHelper**:

```
public static class TransactionHelper
{
    public static void HandleTransaction(Action action)
    {
        using (var tx = CreateScope())
        {
            action();
            tx.Complete();
        }
    }

    private static TransactionScope CreateScope(IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
    {
         var tOptions = new TransactionOptions
                                 {
                                     IsolationLevel = isolationLevel,
                                     Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
                                 };
         return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tOptions);
    }

}
```

This was working perfectly well without any problem, however recently after I started to see these exceptions, I have been told that this implementation might lead into a deadlocks, as the unit of work is a transaction (Business Transaction - [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)) inside a transaction scope, is that possible to be the reason? and if so, what can be the alternative implementation if needed?

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurred by several reasons like transaction timeout, nesting two transactions inside each other, two open connection inside of transaction scope, using single `DbContext` instance for entire web application and hence DbContext has it's own UOF, it may some conflict occurs between theme for some reason. You can use `System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status` for identifying status of transaction and it my aborted before exception thrown.

Change `return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, tOptions);` to `return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, tOptions);` and test it again and see what happen.